# RSA with a prime substituted by a Carmichael number

Tags: rsa

If the public key in a RSA system is $(n,e)$ with $n=pq$, $p$ prime, $q <p$ a Carmichael number and $\gcd(e,(p-1)(q-1))=1$ then if $d$ is the inverse of $e$ modulo $k=(p-1)(q-1)$, I want to show that for every $0<M<n$ we have that $M^{ed}\equiv M (\hspace{-2mm}\mod n)$.

I've managed to prove it is true if the $\gcd(M,n)=1$.

If $\gcd(M,n)>1$, I've make two cases, $p|M$ or $p\not|M$. For the first case I also know it is true, but I'm not able to prove the second case.

Any ideas?

And, if it is possible, I'd like to prove it just using the definition of Carmichael numbers, i.e., for every $a \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\gcd(a,q)$ we have that $a^q \equiv a (\hspace{-2mm}\mod q)$. I know there is an equivalent definition by Korselt's criterion, but we haven't studied it and I'd like to prove it without using it.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No, it's trying to prove things according to my actual knowledge, altough maybe it is not possible to do it.

Comment: Hint: Prove that $M^{e\,d}\equiv M\pmod p$. Prove that $q$ is square-free. Prove that $M^{e\,d}\equiv M\pmod q$. Prove that $p$ and $q$ are coprime. Conclude that $M^{e\,d}\equiv M\pmod n$.

Comment: @fgrieu I think I explained myself very badly, that's what happens when you post a question in a hurry. That's the scheme I was following in the prove. Thats how I've proven the case when $\gcd(M,n)=1$, my problem is that I don't know how to prove that $M^{e\,d}\equiv M\pmod q$ when $\gcd(M,q)>1$.

Comment: To prove that $M^{e\,d}\equiv M\pmod q$ regardless of $M$, prove that $M^{e\,d}\equiv M\pmod r$ for all primes $r$ dividing $q$. Then use that if $x$ is a multiple of each prime $r$ divisor of a square-free $q$, then $x$ is a multiple of $q$.